# Parallelism in simple prime search function

Tags: haskell

I am trying to learn concurrency and parallelism in Haskell.
And I just started Simon Marlow's book. Not everything is clear though.
And there aren't many (if any) simple examples on the internet.

This is just a simple prime search function for learning purposes.
Can this be parallelised? And if yes, can someone show an example with this function.

```
main = mapM_ print [x | x <- [2..], isPrime x]

isPrime :: Integer -> Bool
isPrime n = odd n && all (\ f -> n `mod` f /= 0) [3..(ceiling $ sqrt $ fromIntegral n)]
```

I understand that I can use Strategies to map through a list in parallel.
How, for instance, would I test factors in the list in batches of 8, doing 8 tests in parallel? 
I would love an example please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is also available as a .lhs file at http://lpaste.net/143207

The basic idea is that whenever you have an expression like:

```
map f xs
```

you can replace it with:

```
parMap strat f xs
```

to spawn off the map computation as sparks so that it will
be executed in parallel in the threaded runtime.
A typical choice for `strat` is `rdeepseq` - see [Basic Strategies](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parallel-3.2.0.6/docs/Control-Parallel-Strategies.html#g:4) for other options.

The problem is that spawning every single call to `f` as
a spark may not be cost effective. To realize any speedup
you may have to organize the work so that a spark is responsible
for calling `f` on a range of elements of the list.

Let's write `isPrime` like this:

```
-- original version
isPrime0 n = and $ map notfactor [2..limit]
  where limit = div n 2
        notfactor f = mod n f /= 0
```

(I've purposely extended the factor testing range so we don't
have to use large prime numbers for our tests.)

The first idea would be to simply change the `map` into `parMap rdeepseq`:

```
-- spawn each call to notfactor as a spark
isPrime1 n = and $ parMap rdeepseq notfactor [2..limit]
  where limit = div n 2
        notfactor f = mod n f /= 0
```

If you benchmark this, however, you'll find
out this runs a lot slower than the sequential version.

The next idea is to break up the range `[2..limit]` into
a small number of chunks like this:

```
-- evaluate the notfactor calls in ranges -- not parallized
isPrime2 n = and $ map (\r -> all notfactor r) ranges
  where limit = div n 2 -- ceiling $ sqrt $ fromIntegral n
        notfactor f = mod n f /= 0
        ranges = chunks 3 limit 10
```

Here `chunks a b k` is a function which splits the
list `[a..b]` into `k` equal sized ranges.

To get a parallized version, we change the `map` call
into `parMap rdeepseq`:

```
-- evaluate the notfacto calls in ranges - parallelized
isPrime3 n = and $ parMap rdeepseq (\r -> all notfactor r) ranges
  where limit = div n 2
        notfactor f = mod n f /= 0
        ranges = chunks 3 limit 10
```

Some rough timings (in seconds) for the prime 15485863 and
RTS option `-N1` vs. `-N2`:

```
              -N1      -N2
isPrime0    0.624    0.673
isPrime1   12.---   12.---
isPrime2    0.573    0.603
isPrime3    0.563    0.365
```

As you can see, `isPrime3` does exhibit some speedup. The timing for `isPrime1` is due to the fact that it is creating several million sparks compared to `isPrime3` which only creates 10 sparks.

For completeness, here's the code for `chunks` and the
program driver.

```
-- divide a range into equal size chunks
chunks :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> [[Integer]]
chunks a b k = 
  let (q,r) = divMod (b - a) k
      sizes = replicate (fromIntegral r) (q+1) ++ replicate (fromIntegral (k-r)) q
      go x [] = []
      go x (y:ys) = [x..x+y-1] : go (x+y) ys
  in go a sizes

main :: IO ()
main = do
  ( which : ps : _ ) <- getArgs
  let p = read ps
  case which of
    "0" -> print $ isPrime0 p
    "1" -> print $ isPrime1 p
    "2" -> print $ isPrime2 p
    "3" -> print $ isPrime3 p
```